# In vim, is there a way to delete all current line except the given text object?

Tags: vim

For example, if I have this line

```
printf("something\n"); // any comment
```

Doing `da"` gives me :

```
printf(); // any comment
```

But  I what I would like :

```
"something\n"
```

Comment: So far the better I found is `da"<shift>Vp`

Comment: A wishlist can be added in Vim's issue tracker, like removing rest of the line except selected text. Of course, we can write a function too.

Answer (score 4):

**Efficient answer**

Press `f"d^f"lD` to keep the current object in the current line, deleting rest of them.

```
     f" - find "
     d^ - delete from current cursor position to start of line.
     l - move right
     D - delete from current cursor till end.(d$)
```

*You can create a text object too!*

```
  :nmap de" f"d^f"lD               // de" - delete except double quotes.
```

You can keep the cursor anywhere in the line and press `de"`.

**Edit: previously written answer**

You can press `"sda"` to delete the current object

Then, press `dd` to delete the current line.

Then, press `"sp` to paste the current object.

Totally, `"sda"dd"sp` to keep the current text in the current line.

You can map this to a key like,

```
     :nmap <F5> "sda"dd"sp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_ ................... jump to the first non-blank
f( .................. jump to parenthesis
yi( ................. yank inner ()
dd .................. delete line contents
"0p ................. paste yank register

nnoremap <F2> :exec 'normal _f(yi(dd"0p'<CR>
```

Changing to avoid pasting newline

```
nnoremap <F2> :exec 'normal _f(yi(_dg_"0p'<CR>
```

Instead of using `dd` using `_g_` This avoids copying carrige return

Comment: Interesting approach, and thanks for providing an explanation, but (1) I can’t get it to work right. It puts (pastes) the string from between the parentheses after the first character of the following line. (2) Your answer seems specific to the task of a pair of parentheses. I believe that the question is looking for something more general. Read the question *title*, and realize that the question body says “For example”. Can you develop a solution that answers the question and doesn’t work just for the example?